# how to add existing non-git project to bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I created a project using angular cli. Project is in directory `dw-ng2-app` and it has several files generated by angular cli. I want to create a Bitbucket repository for this. My confusion is, when I create a repository in Bitbucket, it gives me 3 options

1. I create a README and .gitignore file. I cannot use this option as
   then when I try to sync the local project with repository, I get
   error that there is no common history
2. I selected option of starting
   from scratch. The web page listed the commands I should run to clone
   and upload, eg `git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/angularcli.git`
   but this creates a new directory on my local machine named
   angularcli which has .git directory. I am not sure if I can use this
   option as my project is in different directory and moving it to
   angularcli directory might affect it (not sure)
3. 3rd option is to
   mention that I have an existing project. Then I am prompted to use
   the command `git remote add origin
   ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/angularcli.git` but that doesn't
   work as my current project directory is not a git repository

How can I move the angular cli project to bitbucket? Should I have created the repository first and then created angularcli project in the generated directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but the simplest may be to simply make your current project directory, a git repository.

1. Go to your project directory

   cd dw-ng2-app
2. Initialize git repository

   git init .
3. Add your current project to be tracked

   git add --all
4. Make your initial commit

   git commit -m "Initial commit for Angular project"

At that point, you can use the third, "existing project" option within BitBucket.

After you've created a new repo there, you can see its URL and use that to track your new repository with your local one

```
git remote add origin https://username@your.bitbucket.domain:7999/yourproject/repo.git 
git push -u origin master
```

[Here's a complete writeup from BitBucket if you need.][1]

*note* - I used `git add .` originally in my example, and BitBucket recommends `git add --all`. Either of these will work fine in your case.
[1]: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html

Answer (score 1):

If you've created project using **angulat-cli** then it automatically created project with **git initialisation**. It also commits initial changes locally.
So you just have to add **remote origin** and push the content.

-If repository is not initialise as git repository then:

```
cd dw-ng2-app
git add --all
git commit -m "commit message"
git push -u origin master
```

-If already initialise with git repository.
First of all go to directory dw-ng2-app : `cd dw-ng2-app`

add remote to your repository.

```
git remote add bitbucket https://username@your.bitbucket.domain/yourproject/repo.git
```

push the changes:

```
git push -u origin master
```

here's **master** is name of branch in which you want to push the content.

Comment: It is similar to option 2 but it doesn't work. I get error `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. I suppose the error is that this option expects that the current directory is already a git repo (it has .git directory in it).

Comment: if says not a git repository then go to cd-ng2-app and execute `git init` command. It will initialise current directory as git repo.